# Wrong matrix reading with vector<vector<int>> on C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

Hello I pretend while have input read an size n x n of matrix and for each n read matrix , I used a `vector<vector<int>>` to define matrix , my input was :

```
6
100100
001010 
000000 
110000 
111000 
010100
```

and my code is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int n;
  vector<vector<int>> grid;

  while(cin >> n){

    grid.resize(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      grid[i].resize(n);
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        cin>>grid[i][j];
      }
    }

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        cout<<grid[i][j];
      }
      cout<<endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but I don't know why output is:

```
1001001010011000011100010100
000000
000000
000000
000000
000000
```

for my perceptive an line can't have more than 6 numbers and need have 6 number so I don't have idea what it is doing!
Someone can tell me what I 'm doing wrong and explain reason please.

Comment: `cout<<grid[0][i];` You're printing each element of the first line 6 times.

Comment: ok I edited with your correction but the output is incorrect any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter number `100100` it is treated as one integer not 6 integers. You should press `Enter` key after each digit `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the error in printing it out, you have to bear in mind that `100100` itself is an integer and `std::cin::operator>>` will read it at once. To make it read only one `0`/`1` at a time, insert whitespaces inbetween or read from input to intermediate `bool variable` and then copy from that.
Also, if you had just `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`s or `std::vector<std::string>` (that's in case you want to treat it as a text), you wouldn't need that.